# Stitched ripped clothes vs stitched and ripped clothes

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, conjunctions, placement

I think that *stitched ripped clothes are clothes whose the ripped part is stitched* and s*titched and ripped clothes are clothes whose the stitched part is ripped*. Am I right?

In this context, the clothes are **one pair** of clothes.

Comment: Stitched ripped clothes are clothes that are both stitched and ripped. Stitched and ripped clothes could be two lots, one of stitched and another of ripped clothes.

Comment: This is not clear at all. 'Stitched' could refer to the original state of clothing (ie it is made of fabric which is stitched together) or it could mean that it has been *mended* by stitching it. Something could tear along the stitching and you could say that "the stitching has torn", but it does not sound logical to say that something is both stitched (mended) *and* torn (damaged) at the same time.

Comment: @Astralbee you mean both are not clear?

Comment: @brooke Neither.

Comment: There's certainly no relevant syntactic principle whereby including ***and*** or not could reliably distinguish between these two possible meanings. So you won't learn anything about ***grammar*** here. If you really need to distinguish the two types in this particular case, I suggest you stick with ***clothes whose ripped part is stitched*** for the first kind, and ***clothes whose stitched part is ripped*** for the second (in neither case do you want ***the*** after ***whose***).

Comment: ...for the more general case, let's suppose we know what a ***restored** movie* means, AND we know what a ***censored** movie* means. A ***restored censored** movie* would probably refer to a movie which was censored when first released (and perhaps still is) that has been restored. But a ***censored restored** movie* would normally refer to a movie which was censored ***after*** being restored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is often the case with this sort of list, the reality is always going to be ambiguous.

"Stitched, ripped clothes" implies clothes that have been ripped, but then repaired. (Note that I added a comma.)

"Stitched and ripped clothes" similarly implies clothes that have been repaired, but if contrasted with the first example, suggests that further ripping has occurred AFTER the repair. This is quite a weak implication though.

Clothes can generally be assumed to have been stitched as part of the process of creation, however the context here pretty much precludes the possibility that "Stitched" refers to that process.